# Move view from top to bottom continuously without animation in Android

Tags: position, android-animation, collision-detection, move, thread-sleep

I want to know how to move a view from top to bottom continuously without animation. I am asking this because I want to get the position of the view at every step so that I can check that if there is any collision between that view and any other view.

With animation you can move (not exactly move) a view from one position to another position (Animator class), but animation produces an illusion to the user that it is moving but it's position is fixed all the time. So this can't be done using animation?

Second approach is incrementing position of view. I applied this method in `onCreate()`. If I used it without `Thread.sleep(50)` then the activity doesn't show the view, if I applied it with `Thread.sleep(50)` then activity doesn't start for some period.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved the problem using ValueAnimator :-

CodeSnippet :-

```
va=ValueAnimator.ofFloat(0.0f,size.y);
va.setDuration(5000);
va.setRepeatCount(va.INFINITE);
va.setRepeatMode(va.REVERSE);
va.start();
va.addUpdateListener(new AnimatorUpdateListener() {
    @Override
    public void onAnimationUpdate(ValueAnimator animation) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                bullet[0].setTranslationY((Float) va.getAnimatedValue());           
                   Rect R11=new Rect(bullet[0].getLeft(),bullet[0].getTop()+(int)bullet[0].getTranslationY(),bullet[0].getRight(),bullet[0].getBottom()+(int)bullet[0].getTranslationY());
                      Rect R21=new Rect(ball.getLeft(), ball.getTop(), ball.getRight(), ball.getBottom());
                      if(R11.intersect(R21))
                        va.cancel();
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Property animation (subclasses of Animator class) actually move the view, as they update the actual property of the view. It is the view animations (subclasses of Animation class) that don't move the actual view and instead just where it appears to the user. 
Source:http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/graphics/prop-animation.html
Quote: With the property animation system, these constraints are completely removed, and you can animate any property of any object (Views and non-Views) and the object itself is actually modified.

You also shouldn't start moving things around in the onCreate method as things are still initializing (onwindowfocuschanged is recommened). Also if you call thread.sleep, you are going the sleep the main UI thread, hence freezing the application for a time.